# c++ tower of hanoi: the program sometime terminates without completing the tower

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, towers-of-hanoi

I tried to implement tower of hanoi using stack but there seems to be some problem when running the program. It runs fine sometimes but sometimes the program terminates.
I created a separate class to work as stack.

```
class stack{
    int* arr;
    int stackSize;
public:
    stack(int size = 0);
    ~stack();
    void push(int a);
    int pop();
};
stack::stack(int size){
    this->arr = new int(size);
    this->stackSize = 0;
}
stack::~stack(){
    delete []this->arr;
}
void stack::push(int a){
    this->stackSize++;
    int* temp = new int(this->stackSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < this->stackSize; i++){
        temp[i] = this->arr[i];
    }
    temp[this->stackSize-1] = a;
    delete []this->arr;
    this->arr = temp;
}
int stack::pop(){
    if(this->stackSize <= 0){
        cout << "stack underflow" << endl;
    }else{
        this->stackSize--;
        int popped = this->arr[this->stackSize];
        int* temp = new int(this->stackSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < this->stackSize; i++)    {
            temp[i] = this->arr[i];
        }
        delete []this->arr;
        this->arr = temp;
        return popped;
    }
}
```

```
void toh(int n, stack &s, stack &des, stack &aux){
    if (n <= 0)
        return;
    toh(n-1, s, aux, des);
    des.push(s.pop());
    display();
    toh(n-1, aux, des, s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this->arr = new int(size);` does not allocate memory for an array, it allocates for a single integer. You want `this->arr = new int[size];` you do similar in your push function too.

Also, to add, your push should only allocate a new array when it is full.

Also also, in pop, you do not return a value in the case when the if is true. Should either throw an exception, or return a dummy value.